# retrieve newest messages xmpp?

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd, smack

I recently create a chat application (ejabberd and smack). Everything is ok but 2 problem that I can't resolve.

1. I would like to get list of recent messages (list of conversations) from xmpp. But I don't know how to do that.
2. I would like to save thread id of each conversation to mysql but no module can do that.

Someone else can help me? Thank in advance.

Comment: I think you will have to save the messages manually

Comment: Thank @Hosar. I think I don't need to request last messages of conversation list. I should save them on client.

Answer (score 0):

1. You should request recent messages via [XEP-0313](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0313.html). It's functionality is implemented in ejabberd's `mod_mam` module. As far as I know, Smack has support for this too, just make sure you have recent version of the library.
2. There is indeed no module you can use to store conversation identifiers.

Comment: Thank @user2610053, 1 is ok. but 2, As far as I know, conversation identifier is thread id for chat and group chat. I would like to store that for other systems can access to.

Comment: Well, you can craft a module for this.